# How can I get the posix path of a file that is selected by Finder?

Tags: javascript, javascript-automation

I am trying to get the full path of a file that is selected by Finder. At this point, I have tried many methods:

```
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0]
=> Application("Finder").startupDisk.folders.byName("Users").folders.byName("example").folders.byName("Tools").folders.byName("my-tools").documentFiles.byName("example.sh")
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].name()
=> "example.sh"
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].toString()
=> "[object ObjectSpecifier]"
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].posixPath()
!! Error on line 1: Error: Can't get object.
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].path()
!! Error on line 1: Error: Can't get object.
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].url()
=> "file:///Users/example/Tools/my-tools/example.sh"
>>
>> Path(Application('Finder').selection()[0])
!! Error on line 1: Error: Can't get object.
>>
>> Path(Application('Finder').selection()[0]).toString()
!! Error on line 1: Error: Can't get object.
```

None of these commands obtain the posix path which is `/Users/example/Tools/my-tools/example.sh`.

Ultimately, I know I can simply strip the `file://` off of the front of the url:

```
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].url().replace(/^file:\/\//, '')
=> "/Users/example/Tools/my-tools/example.sh"
```

But that seems hacky, and it seems like there should be a command to obtain the posix path directly.

Comment: Also, if there are API docs for JXA, I would be grateful if anyone could point me to them. I know about [the JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook/wiki) and [the JXA Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html), but I don't see any documentation that simply shows all the methods and properties that exist for each object (such as a file).

Comment: JXA uses the AppleEvent definitions provided by automatable applications and scripting extensions, just like AppleScript does. To see the documentation for such a library, open Script Editor, set the Library window to show, locate the relevant application or extension (in this case: Finder) there, double click it to open the Library Viewer. There is a dropdown to select the language in which to display the documentation; if you mostly use JXA, you can also set that as the standard language in Script Editor preferences and the documentation should follow suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examin [the file's `properties()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903800/how-can-i-find-out-all-the-methods-on-a-jxa-object/41903801#41903801), you will see that the only property which contains the full path is the `url()`. However, special characters are escaped and the url is prefixed with the `file://` protocol when using the `url()` property:

```
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].name()
=> "asdf\"asdf.txt"
>>
>> Application('Finder').selection()[0].url()
=> "file:///Users/example/Tools/my-tools/asdf%22asdf.txt"
```

In order to get the POSIX path, you can `unescape()` the `url()` and remove the `file://` protocol from the beginning of the `url()`:

```
>> unescape(Application('Finder').selection()[0].url()).replace(/^file[:]\/\//, '')
=> "/Users/example/Tools/my-tools/asdf\"asdf.txt"
```

Comment: Easier: `Path(decodeURI(Application('Finder').selection()[0].url()))` gets you a valid Path object (JXA’s equivalent to an AppleScript Alias). Encoding and decoding URIs is something where JavaScript _really_ has you covered, and the Path object is smart enough to handle `file://` protocol prefixes.